# React mgt-login Application Roles

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I am using the mgt-login component on my React application, and I want to show different content based on which Application Role the logged in user has.

Is there a way to get the application role of the user from the MSAL2 Provider?

My Provider is defined as

```js
Providers.globalProvider = new Msal2Provider({
  clientId: CLIENT_ID,
  redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from the the `getAllAccounts()[i].idTokenClaims.roles` attribute.

Comment: I tried this under my `Provider.globalProvider` but I get only the id and username. Does your solution apply also for Providers on @microsoft/mgt-element?